# Не обновляются данные из БД на React. Показывает старые записи, в самом MySQL обновляются, соответственно в react-овском html выводится предыдущее

Tags: mysql, node.js, cheerio, nodemon

```
Данные обновляются только в БД, чтобы изменения были и в UI React? то нужно второй раз сохранить файл и затем nodemon второй раз перезапуститься. Я так же заметил, что при обновлении, в реакте отображается предыдущее значение, а в БД, как и сказал ранее, те значение которые уже были внесены.

Код node js(серверной части): `const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const axios = require('axios');
const CyrillicToTranslit = require('cyrillic-to-translit-js');
const iconv = require('iconv-lite');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const db = require('mysql');

let uefaCountryRank = [];

// db MYSQL
const con = db.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'legfootball'
});

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected to DB!");
});

con.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});

const parsing = async () => {
    con.query('SELECT * FROM uefacountryrank', (err, result) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        app.get('/uefaCountryRank', (req, res) => {
            res.send(result);
        });
    });
    await axios.get('https://terrikon.com/football/uefa_coefs') // last 5 uefa season || uefa rank
    .then(response => response.data)
    .then(response => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(response);

        $('tbody tr').eq(0).each((i, element) => {
            uefaCountryRankSeason.push({
                seasonLast5: $(element).find('th').eq(3).text(),
                seasonLast4: $(element).find('th').eq(4).text(),
                seasonLast3: $(element).find('th').eq(5).text(),
                seasonLast2: $(element).find('th').eq(6).text(),
                seasonCurrent: $(element).find('th').eq(7).text(),
            });
        });
        $('tbody tr').each((i, element) => {
            uefaCountryRank.push({
                place: $(element).find('td').eq(0).text(),
                flag: $(element).find('td:nth-child(2) img').attr('src'),
                name: $(element).find('td').eq(2).text(),
                total: $(element).find('td').eq(8).text(),
                quantity: $(element).find('td').eq(9).text(),
                totalLast5: $(element).find('td').eq(3).text(),
                totalLast4: $(element).find('td').eq(4).text(),
                totalLast3: $(element).find('td').eq(5).text(),
                totalLast2: $(element).find('td').eq(6).text(),
                totalCurrent: $(element).find('td').eq(7).text(),
            });
        });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

    // delete then insert in DB uefacountryrankseason
    con.query('DELETE FROM uefacountryrankseason', (err, result) => {
        if(err) throw err;
    });
    con.query(`INSERT INTO uefacountryrankseason (seasonLast5, seasonLast4, seasonLast3, seasonLast2, seasonCurrent) VALUES ('${uefaCountryRankSeason[0].seasonLast5}', '${uefaCountryRankSeason[0].seasonLast4}', '${uefaCountryRankSeason[0].seasonLast3}', '${uefaCountryRankSeason[0].seasonLast2}', '${uefaCountryRankSeason[0].seasonCurrent}')`, (err, result) => {
        if(err) throw err;
    });

    // delete then insert in DB uefacountryrank
    con.query('DELETE FROM uefacountryrank', (err, result) => {
        if(err) throw err;
    });
    uefaCountryRank.map((e) => {
        con.query(`INSERT INTO uefacountryrank (place, flag, name, total, quantity, totalLast5, totalLast4, totalLast3, totalLast2, totalCurrent) VALUES ('${e.place}', '${e.flag}', '${e.name}', '${e.total}', '${e.quantity}', '${e.totalLast5}', '${e.totalLast4}', '${e.totalLast3}', '${e.totalLast2}', '${e.totalCurrent}')`, (err, result) => {
            if(err) throw err;
        });
    });
}

parsing();

setInterval(() => {
    uefaCountryRank.splice(0, uefaCountryRank.length);

    parsing();
}, 120000);

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8888, (err) => {
    if(err) return err;
    console.log('Server on 8888 is running...');
});
`

Код того компонента в реакте, где не обновляются данные или же показывает предыдущее значение при каждом перезапуске: `import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './HotBoard.css';
import $ from 'jquery';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import SwiperCore, { Autoplay } from 'swiper';
import friendly from '../../assets/ico/friendly.webp';
import undefTeam from '../../assets/ico/undefTeam.webp';

SwiperCore.use([Autoplay]);

function HotBoard(props) {
    const[liveMatches, setLiveMatches] = useState();
    const[matchesQuant, setMatchesQuant] = useState('0');

    useEffect(() => {
        const update = () => {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/liveMatches',
            }).done(function (response) {
                setLiveMatches(response && response.map((e, i) => {
                    return  <SwiperSlide key={'key' + i} id={'id' + i} title={e.lName.length > 70 ? 'Товарищеский' : e.lNameRoundDateTime[0] + ' | ' + e.lNameRoundDateTime[1] + ', ' + e.lNameRoundDateTime[2]}>
                                <div className='slideWrap'>
                                    <progress value={e.time === 'Перерыв' ? '45' : e.time.match(/\d+/)} max={'90'}></progress>
                                    <span className="hName">{e.hName.slice(0, 10)}</span>
                                    {e.hLogo === undefined ? <img width={'13px'} src={undefTeam} alt={e.hName} title={e.hName} /> : <img src={e.hLogo} alt={e.hName} title={e.hName} />}
                                    <span className='hScore'>{e.hScore}</span>
                                    <div className="lLogoTime">
                                        {e.lLogo === undefined ? <img src={friendly} alt={e.lNameRoundDateTime[0]} width={'14px'} /> : <img width={'14px'} src={e.lLogo} alt={e.lNameRoundDateTime[0]} />}
                                        <span className="time">{e.time === 'Перерыв' ? 'Пер.' : e.time}</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <span className='aScore'>{e.aScore}</span>
                                    {e.aLogo === undefined ? <img width={'13px'} src={undefTeam} alt={e.aName} title={e.aName} /> : <img src={e.aLogo} alt={e.aName} title={e.aName} />}
                                    <span className="aName">{e.aName.slice(0, 10)}</span>
                                </div>
                            </SwiperSlide>
                })); 
                setMatchesQuant(response.length);
                if(response.length > 0) document.querySelector('#hotBoard .liveWrap span').style.color = 'red';
            });
        }

        update();
        setInterval(() => {
            update();
        }, 30000);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div id="hotBoard">
            <Swiper centeredSlides={true} grabCursor={true} speed={5000} autoplay={{delay: 1, disableOnInteraction: false}} slidesPerView={2} breakpoints={{280: {slidesPerView: 1}, 540: {slidesPerView: 2}, 768: {slidesPerView: 3}, 1200: {slidesPerView: 5},  1920: {slidesPerView: 6}}} freeMode={true}>
                {liveMatches}
            </Swiper>
            <div className="liveWrap">
                <span title='Live'>{matchesQuant}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default HotBoard;`
```

Comment: А от сервера новые(обновленные) данные приходят?

Comment: Да, при повторной перезагрузки nodemon, а на самой БД без повторной перезагрузки уже все данные обновлены

Comment: Так клиенту приходят свежие данные или сервер не отдает обновленные данные?

Comment: Ну я и говорю, данные приходят на клиент, но только с ПОВТОРНОЙ ПЕРЕЗАГРУЗКОЙ